# Workflow Email Alert using Profile

Tags: workflow, email-template, user

I need to send an email to to a particular profile through workflow.
But when it comes to choosing the Recipient Type, I am unable to choose Profiles.

Is there an alternative for achieving this through Profiles?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean users in a particular profile?

Comment: that's correct so I have users in a particular profile and I want to use that profile

Comment: Create a public group having members of all those in the particular profile. and send email to them. You can write trigger on user to add it to a public group whenever its profile is made the targetted profile.

Comment: yes i thought of that but again I'm creating two separate profile and public group... harder to maintain or is that the only way to go?

Comment: Single profile and one public group. Thats it. Nothing else. No maintenance as its done by trigger.

Comment: so if i add a new user to profile then i will also have to add it to the public group correct?

Comment: Yes. Thats why i suggested using triggers on User object.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal - your second comment is a viable answer; please add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a public group having members of all those in the particular profile. and send email to them. You can write trigger on user to add it to a public group whenever its profile is made the targeted profile.